# On Button Click Duplicate HTML Code

Tags: php, javascript, html

How would I make it so that when I click a button it will duplicate the code below:

```
<li class="widget color-blue">  
                <div class="widget-head">
                    <h3>Work list stuffs</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-content">
                    <p>Accessed from private link Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam magna sem, fringilla in, commodo a, rutrum ut, massa. Donec id nibh eu dui auctor tempor. Morbi laoreet eleifend dolor. Suspendisse pede odio, accumsan vitae, auctor non, suscipit at, ipsum. Cras varius sapien vel lectus.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
```

How would I do this? I think it might need Javascript...

Comment: Yes, I bet it might :-))

Answer (score 5):

Look into the [jQuery Clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

The following jQuery code

```
$('.hello').clone().appendTo('.goodbye');
```

Would produce:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">
    Goodbye
    <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**In *raw JavaScript*, use `cloneNode()`:** ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/9Qfhb/2/))

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="somelist">
    <li id="bar" class="widget color-blue">  
        <div class="widget-head">
            <h3>Work list stuffs</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-content">
            <p>Accessed from private link Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam magna sem, fringilla in, commodo a, rutrum ut, massa. Donec id nibh eu dui auctor tempor. Morbi laoreet eleifend dolor. Suspendisse pede odio, accumsan vitae, auctor non, suscipit at, ipsum. Cras varius sapien vel lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<a id="foo" href="#">Duplicate</a>
```

**JS:**

```
var link = document.getElementById('foo');
link.onclick = function() {
    var list = document.getElementById('somelist');
    var item = document.getElementById('bar');
    var clone = item.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = '';
    list.appendChild(clone);
};
```

Or, if you use **jQuery**, use jQuery's [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="somelist">
    <li id="bar" class="widget color-blue">  
        <div class="widget-head">
            <h3>Work list stuffs</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-content">
            <p>Accessed from private link Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam magna sem, fringilla in, commodo a, rutrum ut, massa. Donec id nibh eu dui auctor tempor. Morbi laoreet eleifend dolor. Suspendisse pede odio, accumsan vitae, auctor non, suscipit at, ipsum. Cras varius sapien vel lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<a id="foo" href="#">Duplicate</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    $('#bar').clone().appendTo('#somelist');
});
```

**Example:** [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9Qfhb/)

Comment: when I click the href nothing happens (using the raw javascript method)?

Comment: when I click the href nothing happens (using the raw javascript method)?

Comment: @user65 try the new example. Assuming you are using Internet Explorer, this might have fixed it. If not: tinker some more until you get it to work; you should be really close.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/)...

```
var HTMLstr = '<li class="widget color-blue"><div class="widget-head"><h3>Work list stuffs</h3></div><div class="widget-content"><p>Accessed from private link Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam magna sem, fringilla in, commodo a, rutrum ut, massa. Donec id nibh eu dui auctor tempor. Morbi laoreet eleifend dolor. Suspendisse pede odio, accumsan vitae, auctor non, suscipit at, ipsum. Cras varius sapien vel lectus.</p></div></li>';

var duplicate = function(){
    $("<div />", { html: HTMLstr }).appendTo("body");
};

$("#duplicateBtn").click(duplicate);
```

...or you could just use [$.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test">
    <li class="widget color-blue">  
        <div class="widget-head">
            <h3>Work list stuffs</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-content">
            <p>Accessed from private link Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam magna sem, fringilla in, commodo a, rutrum ut, massa. Donec id nibh eu dui auctor tempor. Morbi laoreet eleifend dolor. Suspendisse pede odio, accumsan vitae, auctor non, suscipit at, ipsum. Cras varius sapien vel lectus.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>

<button id="copy" onClick="copy()">Button B</button>

<div id="test2"></div>

var copy = function(){

    document.getElementById( "test2" ).innerHTML = document.getElementById( "test" ).innerHTML;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using javascript, listen for the button being clicked and then insert code at a certain place like between  or .

Try [javascript events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)  or [jquery html manipulation](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_html.asp) for good example of how to listen for an event like clicking a button and executing new code.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("li").clone().appendTo("body");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="x" style="display: block;" onclick="document.getElementById('x').style.display = 'none'">Clone</button>
<li class="widget color-blue">  
                <div class="widget-head">
                    <h3>Work list stuffs</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-content">
                    <p>Accessed from private link Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam magna sem, fringilla in, commodo a, rutrum ut, massa. Donec id nibh eu dui auctor tempor. Morbi laoreet eleifend dolor. Suspendisse pede odio, accumsan vitae, auctor non, suscipit at, ipsum. Cras varius sapien vel lectus.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
</body>
</html>
```